# Cannot insert into database with prepared statements

Tags: java, mysql, database, string

I'm trying to enter into a table called services, and it has an id, service_name and service_type. I get an error when I try to run it.

```java
public void insertService(String service, String serviceType) {

    try {
        st = myConn.createStatement();
        String query = "INSERT INTO services"
                         +"(service_name, service_type)"
                         +"values(?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, service);
        preparedStmt.setString(2, serviceType);

        st.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot Add service" + e);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no need for posting error/exception message at all.

Comment: Why is that lad? What type of statements should I have the exception

Comment: `I get an error when I try to run it.` Maybe some hint, what kind of error do you get? Like `Id value cannot be null`?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: ID is auto acceding in my DB

Comment: why are you using statement and prepared statement? why are you passing in the query into executeupdate?

Comment: @isaace That seems to be what was causing the issue. See my answer.

Comment: I was using a prepared statement because I have read it prevents against sql injection. I could be wrong

Comment: That's right, not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myConn does not appear to be defined.

```
Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user, password);
```

**EDIT 1**

Maybe because you're executing the query without the values?

`st.executeUpdate(query);` versus `preparedStmt.executeUpdate()`

**EDIT 2**

> myConn does not appear to be defined.
>
> `Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user, password);`

Ignore this bit. The answer was in the first edit.

Comment: My apologies, myConnis defined in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

You are missing spaces in your query in several places.  Try:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO services "
                         +"(service_name, service_type) "
                         +"values(?,?)";
```

It is always recommended to run your query manually before putting it in your code to verify it is syntactically correct/valid.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the error is MySQLSyntaxErrorException. You should be looking your sql query generated.

Use below query

```
String query = "INSERT INTO services "
                         +"(service_name, service_type) "
                         +"values(?,?)";
```

An space before double quote of every line